# Updating settings page with only one "save changes" button

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Was wondering how it would be possible to make allow a user to make changes to his/her personal settings through a settings.php page, making it possible to change your username, password and email all on the same page. I know how to perform all these tasks I'm just not sure how it would be possible to perform different functions all on the same page with the same "save changes" button.

```
        <div class="form-editinfo">
        <form class="editform" method="POST" action="settings" style="width: 600px;" >
        Name:  <input type="text" name="editname" value="<?php echo $userRow['user_name']; ?>"><br /><br />
  <table border='0' width='55%' cellspacing='0px'>
    <tr><td>Current Password: </td><td><input type="password" name="editcurrpass" placeholder="Enter Current Password"  ></td></tr>
    <br /><tr><td>New Password: </td><td><input type="password" name="editnewpass" placeholder="Enter New Password" ></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Confirm New Password: </td><td><input type="password" name="editconfpass" placeholder="Enter New Password"  ></td></tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="editsubmit" value="Update Settings">
  <?php

  if(isset($_POST['editsubmit'])){

    $newname = trim($_POST['editname']);
    if(!empty($newname)){
      $id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
      $sqlnewname = $auth_user->runQuery("UPDATE users SET user_name='$newname' WHERE user_id='$id'");
      $sqlnewname->execute();
    }else{
      echo "<br/>You must enter a new username!";
    }
    $uname = $userRow['user_name'];

    $currpass = trim($_POST['editcurrpass']);
    $newpass = trim($_POST['editnewpass']);
    $newconfpass = trim($_POST['editconfpass']);
    if(!empty($currpass) || !empty($newpass) || !empty($newconfpass)){
      if(password_verify($currpass, $userRow['user_pass'])){
        if($newpass == $newconfpass){
          $new_password = password_hash($newpass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
          $id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
          $sqlupdpass = $auth_user->runQuery("UPDATE users SET user_pass=:newpass WHERE user_id='$id'");
          $sqlupdpass->execute(array(':newpass'=>$new_password));
          echo "<br />Password updated.";
        }else{
          echo "<br />Passwords do not match.";
        }
      }else{
        echo "<br/>Incorrect Password.";
      }
    }else{
      echo "<br />You did not fill out one or more of the required fields.";
    }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If yes then show us where you are stuck.

Comment: @ShrikantMavlankar check the original post, when hitting submit it returns the error messages from the password change form.

Comment: So you want user to change his/her name and the same time update his password? It is possible but what if user wants to change only his/her name only or just password then you are doing addition tasks which is not necessary required.

Comment: @ShrikantMavlankar What about Twitters settings page for example? It has multiple functions but only one save changes button, that is how I wish to do it.

Comment: Then you also need to use ajax which will check whether you've changed the old value or not if yes then only update, something like that.

Comment: @ShrikantMavlankar Hmmm alright I'll try to figure something out, thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome bro! Let me know if you need further help :)

Comment: @RyanSmith Which errors come up?

Comment: @Rasclatt The error messages from the change password script because that is always being ran no matter what regardless of whether what's in the textbox has been changed. That's the issue.

Comment: Oh I see, that should be fairly easy to fix. Give me a second to rework what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would think about breaking down this piece of code into separate parts (functions or class/methods) which allows you to better-manage your workflow because you can assign human-readable names to functions so they make more sense. Even though there is more code overall, all the functions in this scenario would be hidden as an include. Another upside is that you can reuse these functions elsewhere if need be. Also, it is best to put the business logic before the view and finally, I would add a hidden field in the form used to identify actions and I would also make the password fields an array for easier readability. See if this is more of a desired outcome for error messages:

**/functions/myfunctions.php**

```
// I suggest you use a query engine to run queries, this will return an array
// if toggled to do so. This will save you time and keep queries consistent
function query($con,$sql,$bind = false,$return = false)
    {
        if(is_array($bind) && !empty($bind)) {
            foreach($bind as $key => $value) {
                $bArr[":{$key}"]    =   $value;
            }
        }
        $query  =   $con->runQuery($sql);
        if(!empty($bArr))
            $query->execute($bArr);
        else
            $query->execute();

        if($return) {
            while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $row[]  =   $result;
            }

            return (!empty($row))? $row : array();
        }
    }
// Change password
function changePassword($password,$id,$con)
    {
        $password   =   trim($password);
        if(empty($password))
            return false;
        $password   =   password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $bind       =   array($password,$id);
        query($con,"UPDATE `users` SET `user_pass` = :0 WHERE `user_id` = :1",$bind);

        return true;
    }
// Update name based on user_id
function updateName($name,$id,$con)
    {
        $name   =   trim($name);
        if(empty($name))
            return false;
        $bind   =   array($name,$id);
        query($con,"UPDATE `users` SET `user_name` = :0 WHERE `user_id` = :1",$bind);

        return true;
    }
// Check an array for empty fields
function checkArray($array,&$failed)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            $new[$key]  =   (is_array($value))? checkArray($array) : trim($value);
            if(empty($value))
                $failed[]   =   $key;
        }

        return $new;
    }
// Match two string
function passwordsMatch($pass1,$pass2)
    {
        $pass1  =   trim($pass1);
        $pass2  =   trim($pass2);

        if(empty($pass1) || empty($pass2))
            return false;

        return ($pass1 == $pass2);
    }
// Just wraps the password function
function storedPasswordMatch($password,$hash)
    {
        return password_verify($password,$hash);
    }
// Returns the messaging
function compileMessage($array,$type = 'error')
    {
        return '<span class="'.$type.'">'.implode('</span><br />'.PHP_EOL.'<span class="'.$type.'">',$array).'</span>';
    }
```

**/settings**

```
// Put this logic at the top of the page
// Update action
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'update_account') {
    // Add functions
    require(__DIR__.'/functions/myfunctions.php');
    // Update the name or record error
    if(!updateName($_POST['editname'],$id,$auth_user))
        $error['name']  =   'Name is invalid.';
    // Save a storing variable
    $allowPass  =   false;
    // Check if the passwords array is all filled
    $passwords  =   checkArray($_POST['password'],$allowPass);
    // If any password is not filled out, create error(s)
    if(!empty($allowPass)) {
        // I don't know what your preferred logic is, but this is set up so if
        // the user doesn't fill out all three passwords, then it's assumed
        // no password is being changed, so no error is generated
        if(count($allowPass) < 3) {
            foreach($allowPass as $err)
                $error[$err]    =   ucfirst($err).' password can not be empty.';
        }
    }
    // If all password fields are filled out
    else {
        $pass   =   $passwords['new'];
        $curr   =   $passwords['current'];
        $conf   =   $passwords['confirm'];
        // Check that the new and confirm password match
        $pMatch =   passwordsMatch($pass,$conf);
        // Check that the database password matches current password
        $dMatch =   storedPasswordMatch($curr,$userRow['user_pass']);
        // If new and confirm match
        if($pMatch) {
            // If current and database match
            if($dMatch) {
                // Change the password
                changePassword($pass,$id,$auth_user);
                // Record success
                $message['password']    =   'Password updated.';
            }
            else
                // Record error if in-database password doesn't match
                $error['password_match']    =   'Password on file does not match.';
        }
        else
            // If the new and confirm don't match record error
            $error['password_match']    =   'Passwords must match.';
    }
}
?>
<div class="form-editinfo">
    <?php
    // Write success messages to page
    if(!empty($message))
        echo compileMessage($message,'message');
    // Write error messages to page
    if(!empty($error))
        echo compileMessage($error);
    ?>
    <form class="editform" method="POST" action="settings" style="width: 600px;" >
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_account" />
    Name:  <input type="text" name="editname" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($userRow['user_name']); ?>">
        <table border='0' width='55%' cellspacing='0px'>
            <tr>
                <td>Current Password: </td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password[current]" placeholder="Enter Current Password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>New Password: </td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password[new]" placeholder="Enter New Password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Confirm New Password: </td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password[confirm]" placeholder="Confirm New Password"  /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <input type="submit" name="editsubmit" value="Update Settings" />
```

Comment: Username does not seem to work, just refreshes the page when clicking the submit button. The change password side of things does return all the correct messages however does not seem to actually make changes in the database.

Comment: Did you switch out your form input names? Just put some `print_r($val); die();` (`$val` being the values that are meant to trigger events like database hits) in the functions in the order they run and you will figure out where the issue is. I don't have your database, so it's hard to trouble shoot the actual working of the db stuff.

Comment: I got it to work by defining $id and $name in settings.php. Thanks for all of your efforts put into helping me with this, very much appreciated.